# Easiest way to compile a Qt application on Win7 x64

Tags: c++, windows, qt, compilation

I wrote a C++ Qt application using Netbeans and Qt SDK installed on my Win7
So, thing is, my windows is amd64, I compiled the application and it crashes on windows xp 32 bits.
To compile I am using MSYS and mingw which comes with Qt SDK.
I used "Dependecy Walker" to see which dlls are beeing linked and it looks like the application is having lots of 64bits dll

It looks like netbeans is not using any Makefile, heres the output when I click "clean and build"

```
    "/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Release.mk QMAKE=/C/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/bin/qmake.exe SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
    make[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Fred/Documents/NetBeansProjects/RadioMovie4'
    /C/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/bin/qmake.exe VPATH=. -spec win32-g++ -o qttmp-Release.mk nbproject/qt-Release.pro
    mv -f qttmp-Release.mk nbproject/qt-Release.mk
    "/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/qt-Release.mk dist/Release/MinGW-Windows/RadioMovie4.exe
    make[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Fred/Documents/NetBeansProjects/RadioMovie4'
    g++.exe -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PHONON_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtNetwork' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon_compat' -I'.' -I'nbproject' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/win32-g++' -o build/Release/MinGW-Windows/LogicaPasta.o LogicaPasta.cpp
    g++.exe -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PHONON_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtNetwork' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon_compat' -I'.' -I'nbproject' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/win32-g++' -o build/Release/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.cpp
    g++.exe -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PHONON_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtNetwork' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon_compat' -I'.' -I'nbproject' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/win32-g++' -o build/Release/MinGW-Windows/MyThread.o MyThread.cpp
    g++.exe -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PHONON_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtNetwork' -

...same thing here

Windows/TelaConfigurarTelas.o TelaConfigurarTelas.cpp
    g++.exe -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PHONON_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -

...same thing here

Windows/LogicaMusica.o LogicaMusica.cpp
    g++.exe -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PHONON_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtNetwork' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon_compat' -I'.' -I'nbproject' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/win32-g++' -o build/Release/MinGW-Windows/MyVideoWidget.o MyVideoWidget.cpp
    g++.exe -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PHONON_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' 

...same thing here

Windows/Configuracao.o Configuracao.cpp
    g++.exe -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PHONON_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtNetwork' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon_compat' -I'.' -I'nbproject' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/win32-g++' -o build/Release/MinGW-Windows/PastaBase.o PastaBase.cpp
    g++.exe -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PHONON_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtNetwork' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon_compat' -I'.' -I'nbproject' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/win32-g++' -o build/Release/MinGW-Windows/TelaVideoController.o TelaVideoController.cpp
    g++.exe -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PHONON_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtNetwork' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon_compat' -I'.' -I'nbproject' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/win32-g++' -o build/Release/MinGW-Windows/RssLabel.o RssLabel.cpp
    g++.exe -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PHONON_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtNetwork' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon_compat' -I'.' -I'nbproject' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/win32-g++' -o build/Release/MinGW-Windows/ProgComercialWrapper.o ProgComercialWrapper.cpp
    g++.exe -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PHONON_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtNetwork' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon_compat' -I'.' -I'nbproject' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/win32-g++' -o build/Release/MinGW-Windows/TelaVideo.o TelaVideo.cpp
    g++.exe -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PHONON_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtNetwork' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon_compat' -I'.' -I'nbproject' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/win32-g++' -o build/Release/MinGW-Windows/TelaConfiguracao.o TelaConfiguracao.cpp
    g++.exe -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PHONON_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtNetwork' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon_compat' -I'.' -I'nbproject' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/win32-g++' -o build/Release/MinGW-Windows/BaseWrapper.o BaseWrapper.cpp
    g++.exe -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PHONON_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtNetwork' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon_compat' -I'.' -I'nbproject' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/win32-g++' -o build/Release/MinGW-Windows/TelaPrincipal.o TelaPrincipal.cpp
    g++.exe -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PHONON_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtNetwork' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon_compat' -I'.' -I'nbproject' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/win32-g++' -o build/Release/MinGW-Windows/ItemDeProgramada.o ItemDeProgramada.cpp
    g++.exe -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PHONON_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtNetwork' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon_compat' -I'.' -I'nbproject' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/win32-g++' -o build/Release/MinGW-Windows/LogicaHorarioSeqProg.o LogicaHorarioSeqProg.cpp
    g++.exe -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PHONON_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtNetwork' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon_compat' -I'.' -I'nbproject' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/win32-g++' -o build/Release/MinGW-Windows/LogicaCampanha.o LogicaCampanha.cpp
    g++.exe -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PHONON_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtNetwork' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon_compat' -I'.' -I'nbproject' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/win32-g++' -o build/Release/MinGW-Windows/LeitorRss.o LeitorRss.cpp
    g++.exe -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PHONON_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtNetwork' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon_compat' -I'.' -I'nbproject' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/win32-g++' -o build/Release/MinGW-Windows/LogicaSequenciaProgramada.o LogicaSequenciaProgramada.cpp
    g++.exe -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PHONON_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtNetwork' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon_compat' -I'.' -I'nbproject' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/win32-g++' -o build/Release/MinGW-Windows/LogicaSequenciaPadrao.o LogicaSequenciaPadrao.cpp
    g++.exe -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PHONON_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtNetwork' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon_compat' -I'.' -I'nbproject' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/win32-g++' -o build/Release/MinGW-Windows/ProgMusicalWrapper.o ProgMusicalWrapper.cpp
    C:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/bin/moc.exe -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PHONON_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtNetwork' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon_compat' -I'.' -I'nbproject' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/win32-g++' -D__GNUC__ -DWIN32 MyVideoWidget.h -o moc_MyVideoWidget.cpp
    g++.exe -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PHONON_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtNetwork' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon_compat' -I'.' -I'nbproject' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/win32-g++' -o build/Release/MinGW-Windows/moc_MyVideoWidget.o moc_MyVideoWidget.cpp
    C:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/bin/moc.exe -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PHONON_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtNetwork' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon_compat' -I'.' -I'nbproject' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/win32-g++' -D__GNUC__ -DWIN32 RssLabel.h -o moc_RssLabel.cpp
    g++.exe -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PHONON_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtNetwork' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon_compat' -I'.' -I'nbproject' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/win32-g++' -o build/Release/MinGW-Windows/moc_RssLabel.o moc_RssLabel.cpp
    C:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/bin/moc.exe -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PHONON_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtNetwork' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon_compat' -I'.' -I'nbproject' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/win32-g++' -D__GNUC__ -DWIN32 LeitorRss.h -o moc_LeitorRss.cpp
    g++.exe -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PHONON_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtNetwork' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon_compat' -I'.' -I'nbproject' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/win32-g++' -o build/Release/MinGW-Windows/moc_LeitorRss.o moc_LeitorRss.cpp
    C:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/bin/moc.exe -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PHONON_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtNetwork' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon_compat' -I'.' -I'nbproject' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/win32-g++' -D__GNUC__ -DWIN32 TelaVideoController.h -o moc_TelaVideoController.cpp
    g++.exe -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PHONON_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtNetwork' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon_compat' -I'.' -I'nbproject' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/win32-g++' -o build/Release/MinGW-Windows/moc_TelaVideoController.o moc_TelaVideoController.cpp
    C:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/bin/moc.exe -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PHONON_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtNetwork' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon_compat' -I'.' -I'nbproject' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/win32-g++' -D__GNUC__ -DWIN32 TelaPrincipal.h -o moc_TelaPrincipal.cpp
    g++.exe -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PHONON_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtNetwork' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon_compat' -I'.' -I'nbproject' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/win32-g++' -o build/Release/MinGW-Windows/moc_TelaPrincipal.o moc_TelaPrincipal.cpp
    C:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/bin/moc.exe -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PHONON_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtNetwork' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon_compat' -I'.' -I'nbproject' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/win32-g++' -D__GNUC__ -DWIN32 TelaVideo.h -o moc_TelaVideo.cpp
    g++.exe -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PHONON_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtNetwork' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon_compat' -I'.' -I'nbproject' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/win32-g++' -o build/Release/MinGW-Windows/moc_TelaVideo.o moc_TelaVideo.cpp
    C:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/bin/moc.exe -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PHONON_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtNetwork' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon_compat' -I'.' -I'nbproject' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/win32-g++' -D__GNUC__ -DWIN32 TelaConfiguracao.h -o moc_TelaConfiguracao.cpp
    g++.exe -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PHONON_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtCore' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtNetwork' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/QtGui' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/ActiveQt' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/include/phonon_compat' -I'.' -I'nbproject' -I'.' -I'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/mkspecs/win32-g++' -o build/Release/MinGW-Windows/moc_TelaConfiguracao.o moc_TelaConfiguracao.cpp
    windres -i RadioMovie4_resource.rc -o build/Release/MinGW-Windows/RadioMovie4_resource_res.o --include-dir=. -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PHONON_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN
    g++ -Wl,-s -mthreads -Wl,-subsystem,windows -o dist/Release/MinGW-Windows/RadioMovie4.exe object_script.RadioMovie4  -L'c:/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/mingw/lib' -lmingw32 -lqtmain build/Release/MinGW-Windows/RadioMovie4_resource_res.o -lphonon4 -lQtGui4 -lQtNetwork4 -lQtCore4 
    make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Fred/Documents/NetBeansProjects/RadioMovie4'
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Fred/Documents/NetBeansProjects/RadioMovie4'


    BUILD SUCCESSFUL (time:  30s)
```

I want to make my application 32 bit and get it running on windows XP and win 7 32 and 64 bit. Do I need to recompile Qt ? If so how can I do that?
Or I can use those dll that came with the QtSDK

PS: I could use both static and dynamic linkage

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK the mingw with QtSDK is 32-bit, so is the default Qt build. So by default your app is built 32-bit and depends on **32-bit** Qt DLLs and mingw runtime unless you have configured it otherwise. What 64-bit DLLs does the application depend on? What is the crash message on Windows XP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wonder why not use [Qt Creator](http://qt-project.org/downloads), probably there is a chance you didn't know about it? 
Qt uses its own build system called QMake, and QtCreator works nicely with it , so to me, the best answer to your question is: "use QT Creator"